# Linuxbrew, install postgres and start service automatically

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, homebrew, linuxbrew

I install Postgresql on my Ubuntu with:

`brew install postgres`

now I have:

```
psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.5.0
```

How can I start the service automatically?

On my Mac with homebrew I can do it with:

```
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

but how on Ubuntu with Linuxbrew?

I try with:

`brew services start postgresql`

but it says:

```
sh: 1: list: not found
Error: Could not read the plist for `postgresql`!
```

What to do?

Answer (score 18):

Not *quite* automatic but a step in the right direction. On my system I did the following:

```
$ pg_ctl start -D $HOME/.linuxbrew/var/postgres -l logfile
```

You could simple create an alias in your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` something like:

```
alias poston="pg_ctl start -D $HOME/.linuxbrew/var/postgres -l logfile"

alias postoff="pg_ctl stop -D $HOME/.linuxbrew/var/postgres"
```

To test it all out (assuming you do not yet have a database on your machine) you can also create a database for your current user:

```
$ poston
$ createdb `whoami`
$ psql
```